# How do I deserialize a marshmallow_jsonapi.flask schema field into a SQLAlchemySchema PostgreSQL JSONB field?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

I have a Flask model with a field called `metadata` of the `JSONB` type in PostgreSQL.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(128), primary_key=True)
    metadata = db.Column(JSONB)
```

I'm serializing that as a `marshmallow_jsonapi.flask` Schema (`ma` is my environment's Marshmallow object):

```
from marshmallow_jsonapi import fields
class FooSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    id = fields.Str()
    metadata = fields.Raw()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        type_ = "foo"
        self_view = "foo_detail"
        self_view_kwargs = {"foo_detail": "<id>"}
        self_view_many = "foo_list"
```

Then I'm trying to use a `flask_rest_json_api` API to deserialize the requests:

```
from api.models import Foo
from flask_rest_jsonapi import ResourceList
class FooList(ResourceList):
    def get(self):
        schema = FooSchema(many=True)
        query = Foo.query
        return paginate(query, schema)

    def post(self):
        schema = FooSchema()
        foo = schema.load(request.json)

        db.session.add(foo)
        db.session.commit()
```

When I POST the request, the incoming JSON gets properly deserialized into the `foo` object as far as I can tell, but the `.add()` method fails.

```
...
db.session.add(foo)
...
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.dict' is not mapped
```

It looks like the ORM is getting a `dict` that it cannot map to the correct PostgreSQL data type.

Should the `ma.SQLAlchemySchema` instance use something other than `fields.Raw()` to serialize the JSONB field? Should I process the `Foo` instance after calling `schema.load()`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try [marshmallow_sqlalchemy SQLAlchemyAutoSchema](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) object to automatically generate fields for a model, and set the **load_instance** to true in metaclass

```
from marshmallow_jsonapi import fields
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

class FooSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    id = fields.Str()
    metadata = fields.Raw()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        type_ = "foo"
        self_view = "foo_detail"
        self_view_kwargs = {"foo_detail": "<id>"}
        self_view_many = "foo_list"
        load_instance = True # deserialize to model instances
```